# Zebra RZ400 prints an RFID tag, but encodes the subsequent one

Tags: rfid

I'm trying to use my RZ400 for the first time.  I have placed the RFID tags and the ribbon, calibrated the media and sent the

```
^XA
^RS8
^FO50,50^A0N,65^FDHex Pattern 1^FS
^RFW,H^FD112233445566778899AABBCC^FS
^XZ
```

instructions from the programming manual and a RFID tag is printed.  The problem is that the NEXT tag is the one that gets encoded.

The tags are SMARTRAC 292-2 Belt and the dimensions are 3x0.625 inches.  This is a supported tag according to the vendor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is the ordering of your ZPL commands.

The ^FO line will print a label with "Hex Pattern 1". However, after printing, it will advance a tag. Try the following code and see if the tag is encoded and then printed on:

```
^XA
^RS8
^RFW,H^FD112233445566778899AABBCC^FS
^FO50,50^A0N,65^FDHex Pattern 1^FS
^XZ
```

Hopefully this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me with the same printer, but printing from Label Matrix software. I was using a Confidex Casey that worked out of the box, but then switched to a Confidex Carrier Pro and the problem started to happen.

This happens because the printer is not properly calibrated with the Tag you are using.

You need to follow the instructions on the [Zebra RZ400 Inlay Placement Guidelines](http://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/product-information/en-us/brochures-datasheets/rfid/transponder-guidelines/rz400-r0-r1-en.pdf) for calibrating your Tag. There are three things you can do:

- Run the RFID Calibrate command in the front panel of the printer. Try again.
- If it's still tagging the next one, then run the command again, BUT use the option RESTORE instead to revert the previous calibration. Try again.
- If it STILL doesn't works, you will need to manually calibrate the Pitch value using SetGetDo commands against the printer using the guide in the manual I linked.

Good luck.