# Zebra RZ400 prints an RFID tag, but encodes the next tag

Tags: rfid, zpl

RFID Tag : Tageos EOS500
Printer  : Zebra RZ400

The problem is that the NEXT tag is the one that gets encoded with this ZPL as below.
^XA
^RS8
^RFW,A
^FD112233445566778899001122^FS
^FO10,50^A0N,35^FD112233445566778899001122^FS
^XZ

The media and ribbon was already calibrated.

Comment: Check out this answer and see if it solves your problem:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/24292990/2033457][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24292990/2033457

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, You are either not backfeeding the tag back into the encoder (if the tag is not very "long" (from leading edge to trailing edge)), and/or, you have your read/write power set too high.